# Errors rendering kmz in V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working on a project for flood mapping and have a bunch of kmz files which when viewed in Google Earth render fine, but not when displayed in Google Maps api v3.

The kmz holds polygons showing flood stages over a lake, and in Google Earth islands on the lake are "holes" in the polygons since they never flood. When displaying the kmz in google maps though, the holes become filled in.

Not sure what's going on here, can anyone help? The maps were created using ArcMap tools from shapefiles.

Here's a link to one of them: http://www.frontiernet.net/~wfobtv/inundation/combined/103.kmz
Copy the url into google maps to see what I mean.

Thanks!

Comment: It is also curious that in maps.google.com the flooding seems to stop exactly at the US-Canada border. Those clever Canucks must have invented some anti-flooding device. ;-)